# VS Code and Typescript: Library and several Frontends

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am looking for a way to structure a solution (=several projects). More precise, I would like to build a library, and two applications to consume the library: a web site and a command line tool.

In Visual Studio / C#, this is rather easy. I would create three projects, one for the library, one for the cmd line tool, and one for the graphics output (web, or forms). The last two reference the first. The solution would build all three.

Can I do something similar with VSCode and Typescript? How would I set up the root folder? Subfolders for what would be projects? How do I control what is build? Would I need to call the compiler myself several times?

Or do I use different folders, and close / re-open VSCode as appropriate, and use the generated javascript of the lib in the two user programs?

I'd prefer the integrated version...

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR use [lerna](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/tsconfig.json.md#configuration-inheritance-with-extends).

I recommend the following folder structure

```
 - packages
 ---------- CLI
 ---------- webapp 
 ---------- common  
 - package.json
 - .gitignore 
 - ...
```

Each subfolder in the packages folder has it's own build process, test and publish. The important bit is to keep a unified lifecycle to each package. In the root folder you keep only data for packages upkeep. Mostly running build, test, publish for all (or some) packages together.

The typescript bit is less complex since you will have `.tsconfig` for each package. You can also use the [extend](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/tsconfig.json.md#configuration-inheritance-with-extends) feature of the config file to keep common configuration together in the root of the repo.

A common tool to manage all this instead of using hand made scripts is [lerna](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/tsconfig.json.md#configuration-inheritance-with-extends). Which has a lot of information about managing mono-repos. You might want to check out lerna [bootstrap](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/tsconfig.json.md#configuration-inheritance-with-extends) which helps linking dependent packages together during dev time.